# Date picker format for Blackberry webworks?

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I am unable to change format in Blackberry web works application.
I used this code for date picker

```
<input type="date" name="from_date" id="from_date" />
```

Here it displays date like `yyyy-mm-dd` but I need `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that Blackberry supports the input type=date, seems that it is not possible to change the date format yet.
(Which was also stated on this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format))

I suggest you do one of these things instead :

1. Create a custom date picker using jQuery UI
2. If you want to have the Blackberry feel, create a java extension for the [date picker](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Create_a_date_picker_856987_11.jsp).
3. Let the current input type date format on your app and just build the dd-mm-yyyy format on your javascript using the Date functions.